# Localization in multiple projects solution

Tags: uwp, localization

I have a solution in UWP with 3 different projects (for example: A, B and C). B is the library where A and C projects access to.

I have generated the translations for the A project (using XLF files for the translations) and works OK. I'm using Multilingual App Toolkit (MAT).

Now I have started the translations for the B project (resx files and xlf files are in the B project as in A)

[image]

Despite I have activated MAT also in B project, **I can't add new translation language to B**, so I have created the files manually. Builds with only one warning:

```
GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : warning PRI257: 0xdef00522 - Resources found for language(s) 'es,en-us,eu' but no resources found for default language(s): ''. Change the default language or qualify resources with the default language. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231899
```

It seems like project B doesn't have a default language despite of that it's set in the solution (Package.appxmanifest).

When running the app, none of the localized strings in the B project are shown.

Any idea how can I handle this problem?

Edit 1: I have corrected the warning changing the default language for the project in the Assemby Info. Still, strings are not visible.

Edit 2: The code in the A project and in the B is the same:

```
ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("FileName_StringName");
```

Other detail that might be of interest is that B project classes are (mostly) static.

When initiating the app one of the first thing that happens it's the selection of the app level language:

```
// Hard coded language override     
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "eu"; 
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();   
           Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
```

Edit 3: This is what dumped PRI to XML file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PriInfo>
    <ResourceMap name="CoreTPA" version="1.0" primary="true">
        <Qualifiers>
            <Language>ES,EN-US,EU</Language>
        </Qualifiers>
        <ResourceMapSubtree name="CoreTPA">
            <ResourceMapSubtree name="Resources">
                <NamedResource name="AuroraForecastImages_GetForecast_ErrorDeserializingData" uri="ms-resource://CoreTPA/CoreTPA/Resources/AuroraForecastImages_GetForecast_ErrorDeserializingData">
                    <Candidate qualifiers="Language-EU" type="String">
                        <Value>Error deserializing data</Value>
                    </Candidate>
                    <Candidate qualifiers="Language-ES" isDefault="true" type="String">
                        <Value>Error deserializing data</Value>
                    </Candidate>
                    <Candidate qualifiers="Language-EN-US" type="String">
                        <Value>Error deserializing data</Value>
                    </Candidate>
                </NamedResource>
                <NamedResource name="AuroraForecastImages_GetForecast_ErrorGettingDataFromServerIsNetworkWorkingCorrectly" uri="ms-resource://CoreTPA/CoreTPA/Resources/AuroraForecastImages_GetForecast_ErrorGettingDataFromServerIsNetworkWorkingCorrectly">
                    <Candidate qualifiers="Language-EU" type="String">
                        <Value>Error getting data from server. 
Is network working correctly?</Value>
                    </Candidate>
                    <Candidate qualifiers="Language-ES" isDefault="true" type="String">
                        <Value>Error getting data from server. 
Is network working correctly?</Value>
                    </Candidate>
                    <Candidate qualifiers="Language-EN-US" type="String">
                        <Value>Error getting data from server. 
Is network working correctly?</Value>
                    </Candidate>
                </NamedResource>
            </ResourceMapSubtree>
        </ResourceMapSubtree>
        <ResourceMapSubtree name="Files">
            <ResourceMapSubtree name="CoreTPA">
                <NamedResource name="Core_ml.xml" uri="ms-resource://CoreTPA/Files/CoreTPA/Core_ml.xml">
                    <Candidate type="Path">
                        <Value>CoreTPA\Core_ml.xml</Value>
                    </Candidate>
                </NamedResource>
            </ResourceMapSubtree>
        </ResourceMapSubtree>
    </ResourceMap>
</PriInfo>
```

Comment: Could you please provided us detailed code about how to call and show the localized strings in the B project?

Comment: I'm curious why you override the default language (unless it's just for testing?). Can you see if the 'B' resources are in the PRI file for 'A'? Something like this (away from PC):  `makepri /dump /if resources.pri /of resources.xml /dt basic`

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Yes. Just for testing and not spend time changing in settings.
There's only one PRI file inside B project. I'm going to update the question with dumped data from the xml file .

Comment: If you dump the PRI file from the main project after you have built it (with the reference to the shared library) you should see that all the resources are copied in, but the name begins with the shared library name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By testing, the localized resources used by project B come from project A(if project A calls project B) or project C(if project C calls project B) instead of the localized resources added in project B.

Therefore, there is no need to add resource files manually in project B. You need to add your string resources in project A or project C instead of project B.

Comment: Localized resources are supported in libraries. You should not need to copy them into the main projects.

Answer (score 1):

The resources from the library are added to a separate resource map, based on the name of the library itself. For example, if I have the following project setup (where `MainUwpApp` has a reference to `UwpClassLibrary`):

#### MainUwpApp (EXE Project)

```
Strings\Resources.resw
  Resource Name = Source, Value = Main App
```

#### UwpClassLibrary (DLL Project)

```
Strings\Resources.resw
  Resource Name = Source, Value = Class Library
```

..then when I build the EXE and dump the resources file, I see something like this:

```
> makepri dump -if resources.pri -of resources.xml -dt basic
Output File at resources.xml
Successfully Completed

>findstr Source resources.xml

  <NamedResource name="Source" uri="ms-resource://{GUID}/Resources/Source">
  <NamedResource name="Source" uri="ms-resource://{GUID}/UwpClassLibrary/Resources/Source">
```

From here you can see that the two resources named `Source` exist in two separate resource sub-maps. At runtime, you can see them both like this:

```
var map = ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap;

var appResource = map["Resources/Source"];
Debug.WriteLine($"URI: {appResource.Uri}, Value: {appResource.Candidates[0].ValueAsString}");

var libraryResource = map["UwpClassLibrary/Resources/Source"];
Debug.WriteLine($"URI: {libraryResource.Uri}, Value: {libraryResource.Candidates[0].ValueAsString}");
```

Which results in:

```
URI: ms-resource://{GUID}/Resources/Source, Value: Main App
URI: ms-resource://{GUID}/UwpClassLibrary/Resources/Source, Value: Class Library
```